# regular expression to find the merge section in the line

Tags: java, regex

my sentence looks like this

> "abc efg hij klm vdfjgdf dfkgrt r4645 45.567.34.675 435.56.234.435
>   Appleabc efg hij klm vdfjgdf dfkgrt r4645 45.567.34.675 435.56.234.435
>   Orange"

In my sentence all the words are repeated twice except Apple and Orange.
I need regular expression to find the highlighted/bold part

> "abc efg hij klm vdfjgdf dfkgrt r4645 45.567.34.675 435.56.234.435
>   Apple**abc efg hij klm vdfjgdf dfkgrt r4645 45.567.34.675
>   435.56.234.435 Orange**"

I tried with `"abc\sefg\s.+?Orange"`, where it is taking the whole sentense. Kindly help

Comment: The problem is that `.+?` will try to match as little as possible but starting from the beginning, i.e. the first `abc efg` matches and the rest of the expression would try to match until the first `Orange` is found. Depending on your data you could try to match until the next `abc efg` or the end if the input, i.e. use a positive look-ahead, e.g. like this: `abc\sefg\s.+?(?=abc\sefg|$)`

Answer (score 3):

Find "something" (`(.*)` - mind the group) and match it again after another "somehting" by using a back reference (`\1` - matches the previously found group):

```
(.*).*(\1.*)
```

What you want is in the second capture group.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nK9vK4/1

Java demo: https://ideone.com/4G8paV

Answer (score 0):

Dimitry is right. An example using `String#replaceAll()` is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abc efg hij klm vdfjgdf dfkgrt r4645 45.567.34.675 435.56.234.435 Appleabc efg hij klm vdfjgdf dfkgrt r4645 45.567.34.675 435.56.234.435 Orange";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("^(\\w+).*(\\1.*)","$2"));
}
```

O/P :

```
abc efg hij klm vdfjgdf dfkgrt r4645 45.567.34.675 435.56.234.435 Orange
```